# C# SQL select function

Tags: sql, asp.net, select

Function of code: check department number with the clients & redirect to different page

Problem: the code shown below does not work, how should I fix it?

```
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();

command.Connection = connection;

string Query1 = "Select Department from Registration where [Name] ='" + TextBox1.Text + "' and [Password] ='" + TextBox2.Text + "'";
command.CommandText = Query1;

Object DepartmentId = command.ExecuteScalar();

if (DepartmentId != null)
{
    int number = Convert.ToInt32(DepartmentId);
    connection.Close();
    connection.Dispose();
}

if (DepartmentId == "1")
{
    Response.Redirect(ResolveClientUrl("~/Report.aspx"), true);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by _does not work_?

Comment: It cannot redirect to others page when the login user is correct.  Do i have any logical or coding problems?

Comment: Have you checked the value of the `number`?

Comment: You can debug it to find where has the problem.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Thanks for your comment but i still have the functions problems><  i will pay attention to security as well

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

ExecuteNonQuery : this is used for Update and Delete query and returns the no of rows affected.

Execute Sclar : Returns only one selected value.

> int number = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Replace with the below code

```
Object DepartmentId = command.ExecuteScalar();
if(DepartmentId != null)
  int number = Convert.ToInt32(DepartMentId);
   connection.Close();
   connection.Dispose();
```

Update:

```
Object DepartmentId = command.ExecuteScalar();
 connection.Close();
 connection.Dispose();

int number = 0;
     if (DepartmentId != null)
       {
           number = Convert.ToInt32(DepartmentId);

       }
    if(number == 1)
    {
      //..
    }
```

Comment: what is the meaning of " Int32.TryParse(DepartmentId ,out number);"   and i want to test the number by using "label1.text = DepartmentId". However, it is strange that i cannot do this

Comment: its  converting the Object DepartmentId to (int) number., you can also write int number = Convert.ToInt32(DepartMentId);

Comment: if (DepartmentId ==1)  response.redirect ("Default.aspx") ??    if the department number is 1 , just redirect to Default.aspx .       i am very new to C# so thank for you patience.

Comment: Int32.TryParse(DepartmentId ,out number); this has some errors so that i cannot put

Comment: my mistake, Int32.TryParse(string, out int) is not applicable here. also you can close your connection, after Execute Scalar.

Comment: but i need to check the department number><   is it " If(DepartmentId == 1)" then redirect?  Sorry again for stupid question><

Comment: Yes, If(DepartmentId == 1) looks ok

Comment: if you are still having problem rediracting you can try
Response.Redirect(ResolveClientUrl("~/Report.aspx"), true);

Comment: if ( DepartmentId == 1)    there is a problem "Operator''=='cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'  and i change if (DepartmentId) there is another problem by green underline saying that possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'

Comment: The code modified as above

Comment: if(number == 1) you need to compare  with the number.
int number = Convert.ToInt32(DepartMentId);

Comment: love u so much><  i have done it

Answer (score 2):

You're using `ExecuteNonQuery`, instead use `ExecuteReader` and then get the column values or use `ExecuteScalar` with `count` according to your data model

Comment: If you'd just look at the **documentation** of [OleDbCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you'd see that there **is no `ExecuteQuery`** method on that object ....

Comment: Sorry I meant 'ExecuteReader'